# Что означает имя Вячеслав?

Tags: этимология, ономастика

Скажите, пожалуйста, что означает имя Вячеслав? "-Слав" - понятно, от слова "слава", а что означает первая часть - "вячи-"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вячий (более позднее - вящий) - более сильный, больший. 
Вячеслав - самый славный, славнейший.